# jquery quicksand height in chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, quicksand

I try to include jquery quick sand to my portfolio.
I think in firefox allways height of head ul is good.
Chrome browser cant calculate height of head ul and effect form quicksand is poor.
Anyone can help me?

Demo: http://www.testowa.isterio.pl/test.html

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got your question right.

If you are using images inside a container you should use

```
$(window).ready(function ()
```

instead of

```
$(function() {
```

because images are not loaded in the dom.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think I got your question wrong. Could you explain your problem in more detail?